# Stray MKMapView on my view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

My view controller has decided to add a random MKMapView object, despite only declaring one in the .h file. Originally I had used a .xib to configure the view, but that didn't work correctly and I did it all programmatically. You'll see in the attached image my defined map (top) and a small slice of a map at the bottom. The bottom map is the same height as my toolbar, which I find weird. Where could I look to see a random MKMapView object being declared? [image: Mapview]

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say but I can tell you this looks like a view hierarchy/controller/framing issue since the fragment looks to be exactly the size of a navigation bar.